# Pod level distinct values setup in OpenShift helm | Same Pod cannot use same values

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

We are using OpenShift helm chart for deploying Spring boot application. We have a requirement to have pod level values setup(predefined values) and use it as an environment variable from Java class(Spring boot app). Scenario is explained below:

**Values.yaml:**

```
ENV_KEY:
 - KEY: pod1
 - KEY: pod2
 - KEY: pod3
 - KEY: pod4
```

**Some Java class:**

```
log.info("Key : "+System.getEnv("KEY"));
```

If the app is deployed with 2 replicas(2Pods) then above line should print pod1 or pod2 from the respective pods in the console. And if run with 4 pods it should print:

**POD1 Output:**

```
pod1
```

**POD2 Output:**

```
pod2
```

**POD3 Output:**

```
pod3
```

**POD4 Output:**

```
pod4
```

Right now it's not working may be something needs to be configured in DeploymentConfig.yaml which is missing. Can anyone help if this is feasible to achieve.

Comment: Every replica of a Deployment is identical, and their randomly-assigned names mean there's no easy way to tell which one is "first".  Some options here include creating four separate Deployments (maybe using templating in Helm), using a StatefulSet and switching off the `hostname` value, implementing some sort of leader election in your application, or restructuring your application (maybe using a job queue?) so that the specific pod identities don't matter.

Comment: (Separately, remember that Spring can set properties from environment variables.  I might inject an `@Value("${key}") String key`, or embed this property in a `@ConfigurationProperties` class, and not call `System.getEnv()`.  That will make the setup much easier to write useful unit tests for.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, the order is not important here, POD1 can also print pod2 in console. There are 2 restriction : - Values are predefined And same value should not be used by another pod. I hope this is clear now.

Comment: @DavidMaze, It seems this is marked as Duplicate and i saw the other question but the solution seems not the cleanest. As the value of my key could be quite big and it's not good that we add/append in the hostname/pod name.
Moreover it was answered 4 years ago, did we not have any better solution for this? I am not sure why this requirement is not common, It's a valid usecase.